# Searching O365 mailbox for all messages which don't contain [ in subject line

Tags: powershell, office365

Trying to use PowerShell to search O365 mailbox to get all messages where subject line **doesn't** contain specific string, specifically a square bracket [

The command below works fine in principal to find all messages where subject contains a specific word, but can't get it to work to find all messages where subject DOES NOT contain a specific word (or in this case character [)

```
Search-Mailbox -Identity "fred@email.com" -SearchQuery 'Subject:"*" -[' -EstimateResultOnly
```

The eventual aim is to scan a mailbox to remove all content other than messages which contain square brackets in the subject line, so will use -DeleteContent switch or similar, for now just using -EstimateResultOnly or -LogOnly -LogLevel Full and -TargetFolder -TargetMailbox to see a list of what it finds

What am I missing - all comments appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use a `-filter` with `-notlike` should work.

Comment: Search-Mailbox : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Filter'.